# Pathfinding to waypoints using NavMesh (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding, navmesh

I want to make a simple script, that guides a NavMesh agent to various waypoints. I am new to Unity so I don't know some basic functions yet, which is instead typed in pseudo code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Path_left_blue : MonoBehaviour {

    private Transform target;
    private int wavepointindex = 0;
    public NavMeshAgent agent;

    void Start () {
        target = Waypoints_blue_left.waypoints[0];
    }

    void Update () {
        //Set destination to waypoint
        Vector3 dir = target.position;
        agent.setDestination(dir);

        if (agent is within a close range/touching target waypoint)

            //Remove object if at the last waypoint
            if (wavepointindex == Waypoints_blue_left.waypoints.Length)
                Destroy(gameObject);

            wavepointindex++;
            target = Waypoints_blue_left.waypoints[wavepointindex];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void Update()` function called each frame. So you need a function that check if the agent arrives to point, set the new destination to it.

I changed your code to this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Path_left_blue : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private Transform target;
    private int wavepointindex = -1;
    public NavMeshAgent agent;

    void Start () 
    {
        EnemyTowardNextPos();
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        // agent is within a close range/touching target waypoint
        if (!agent.pathPending && agent.remainingDistance < 0.5f)
        {
            EnemyTowardNextPos();
        }
    }

    void EnemyTowardNextPos ()
    {
        if(wavepointindex == Waypoints_blue_left.waypoints.Length - 1)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            // set destination to waypoint
            wavepointindex++;
            target = Waypoints_blue_left.waypoints[wavepointindex];
            agent.SetDestination(target);
        }
    }
}
```

`EnemyTowardNextPos()` function only called when agent arrives to current point.

I hope it helps you